# How to use a parent type value in another type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am experimenting with writing my own simple ORM.
My code is as below.

```
type Models = {
   User: {
      name: string
   },
   Template: {
      text: string
   }
}

type ExtractKeysFrom<T> = keyof T

type ModelsKeys = ExtractKeysFrom<Models, Object>
// This returns correctly: 'User' | 'Template'

type ORM = {
   model: (modelName: ModelsKeys) => {
      create(props: Models[typeof modelName]): Promise<boolean>
   }
}
```

For the implementation:

```
declare const orm: () => ORM;
orm().model('User').create({
  name: 'Adam'
})
```

I'd like that `props` in `create()` be valid and automatically point to `User` properties only. Instead I am getting:

```
create(props: User | Template): Promise<boolean>
```

I know `typeof modelName` is wrong in this case and likely I should perform some type check with `extends` but not sure how to tackle this right. Can you advise?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without pseudocode or missing types/values so we can immediately get to work on it in our own IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you simply need the `model` function to be generic:

```
type ORM = {
   model: <T extends ModelsKeys>(modelName: T) => {
      create(props: Models[T]): Promise<boolean>
   }
}
```

Here the model name is captured as the type `T` and the return object with the `create` funciton can use that to type it's parameter.

Testing that out seems to do what you want:

```
declare const orm: ORM

orm.model('User').create({ name: 'Foo' }) // fine
orm.model('User').create({ text: 'Foo' }) // error

orm.model('Template').create({ text: 'Foo' }) // fine
orm.model('Template').create({ name: 'Foo' }) // error
```

[See Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGwM5QLxQN4CgoECqqEATgFw74E0B2AhgLYSWrCkCWtA5tVAL4AaPgBUIjMMnrAWVGjRkAPYK3ZdeNfri24A9LqihIsRClQBpCCHRYAostL0AxsEvWAYqTiMAPPCRoglAA8gBGAFYQLgB8egb6UCIAFhzoRtCkEMAArqS06E5wpJkuyCCUAOTEZBVQAD5QFWISUjIVuLjpJgEWVjZQANZWcABm3WYdXcEASjCYcgSMpsiUPiJQEMoQtAjo-mZuqNEAFEsBAHJMsiIAlJjRC-JOmdIQx2BeYKiU+2gA2iIALo3SgABS8jFSEB8oTgcGQEHotFimm0HSQTikmSghXywCgRUYlBmMA6hIAdGcUMcqiRSBUbuTnoiZMdsFAGMxKu44bV+HcEiMuBBcBSqcgadV6Yzma82YZNipGjy4HyBQYyF5SGTSIxKcsac1JK8GUyXqz2UolRUVWqoILhaLdfqAobxMa2jLzW92ZzZDbeQJ1RtikUgA)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `model` as a generic function which gets its type inferred from the parameter:

```
type Models = {
   User: {
      name: string
   },
   Template: {
      text: string
   }
}

type ExtractKeysFrom<T> = keyof T

type ModelsKeys = ExtractKeysFrom<Models>

type ORM = {
   model: <T extends ModelsKeys>(modelName: T) => {
      create(props: Models[T]): Promise<boolean>
   }
}

declare const orm: () => ORM;

orm().model('User').create({ name: 'name' }); // OK
orm().model('User').create({ wrong: 'name' }); // KO
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGwM5QLxQN4CgoECqqEATgFw74E0B2AhgLYSWrCkCWtA5tVAL4AaPgBUIjMMnrAWVGjRkAPYK3ZdeNfri25QkKAFFlpegGNgAaQghUAMVJxGAHhEA+TFADW1uADMoIri64NDwSGhWNh5G7GaW1nYOzmEoqK5BetAA8gBKMB54NIyIKJQuUBDKELQI6CkRCa4AFMXhAHJMsiIAlJjuhfJQpqQQ0hBNYA5gqJT1qADaIgC63ZQACkkcJE4ARnBwyKO06ZraQUimUiNDcLRsUHCkjJRNvRjuuTAA3EGPjK8AOlaKCaAHJiGRQd0AcNRjImtgoAxmJRQciIKCBN0vlAAPS4qBZCy4P6A4HIMEQ0hQmEjMYIqAAdwcPFR6Mx-GxeIJFiyQA)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I've isolated the `model` function for simplicity.

```
type Models = {
    User: {
        name: string;
    };
    Template: {
        text: string;
    };
};

function model<
    ModelName extends keyof Models,
    ModelArgs extends Models[ModelName]
>(model: ModelName) {
    // impl

    return {
        create(props: ModelArgs): any {
            // impl
        },
    };
}

model("User").create({ name: "john" });
// happy

model("User").create({ text: "foobar" });
// not happy, text prop doesnt exist for User
```